# Slow downloads with Google Storage Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, download

I am running into a strange issue downloading files from Google Storage Buckets.

If I am on Linux and run this code, a 64kb PDF file takes like 5 minutes to download.

```
def generate_document(request):
    if not ensure_valid_user(request):
        return redirect('/?result=0')

    try:
        long_name = request.GET['long_name']
        short_name = request.GET['short_name']

        file_data, size = CloudStorageManager.get_file(long_name)

        response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/octet-stream')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(short_name)
        response['Content-Length'] = size

        return response

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Here is the method from `CloudStorageManager` class that is important:

```
class CloudStorageManager:
    # private key file, used for local testing
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'CloudStorageAPIKey.json')

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my.private.bucket")

    @staticmethod
    def get_file(long_name):
        bucket = CloudStorageManager.bucket
        blob = bucket.blob(long_name)

        file_string = blob.download_as_string()

        return file_string, blob.size
```

What I am lost on is that with Linux, if I comment out `response['Content-Length'] = size` from my `generate_document()` method the download occurs at normal speed, however when I go home and get on Windows with that line commented, the download takes 5 minutes again, and works with the line included.

Can someone help explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: No. `blob.size == None`

Answer (score 1):

**Interestingly enough**

I fixed the issue by assigning the `Content-Length` of my response from:

`response['Content-Length'] = size`

to

`response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22096518)

Comment: @RADO this does go directly in context with my question, it is a solution I figured out to fix my problem, the reason I haven't deleted this question (since I found my own answer) is because I'm feeling like what I have done is simply a **bandaid** fix. I did remove the reiterated question though. I would like to find out why this fix was even needed.